# spark-submit myfile.py module not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pip

I have done things similar to this:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/path/to/your/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6

export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

but when I run,

```
spark-submit myfile.py
```

where I wish to import a module I installed using `pip install`, I get this error:

> ImportError: No module named **blank**

where **blank** is basically any module I install with pip.

This must be an easy fix, but I'm not sure which paths need to be corrected.

Comment: How do you set Python interpreter? Do you use local mode or some cluster manager?

Comment: Could you explain how to set the Python interpreter? I'm not sure what you mean. This is being run as a cluster.

Comment: So if it is not local mode you have to install module on each worker.

Comment: I had a line like `try: import numpy except ImportError: import pip pip.main(['install', 'numpy']) import numpy` but i got a pip not installed error. Wouldn't the workers have pip installed if they are running 2.7? Or do I also, need to set the python paths on the workers?

Comment: My suggestion is - provide all the details first. Configuration, cluster manager, where / how you executed `pip` and so on.